# Views Filter by View Field

Tags: views

I've created View with list of entity registrations. This list display users registered for events with info, like conference name (node title), user name etc.

Is it possible to add filter, which contains list of all existing conference names by default? Because right now I have to add values manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter). You can create an entity reference view which will contain the all existing conference names, and then use this view as a filter for the main view.

> This module provides the views filter for entity ID or entity
>   reference fields such as node ID, user ID, taxonomy term ID, term
>   reference field (Drupal core) and entity reference field (Entity
>   reference module).